# iOS Enrollment of device with a PIN code sent by e-mail

Tags: ios, mobile-device-management

In my company, we would use the Apple MDM software linked to Active Directory.
We would use the self enrollment system of iOS devices proposed by OS X Lion Server.
The main problem is that to log-on, the user must input their password on the  (*/MyDevices* web app). 
But **our users don't know their password**, because we use a *biometric system* for the logon on our windows machine.

Is there a way to logon with a PIN number sent by e-mail?
Do you have any advices?

Comment: What precisely does "logon with a PIN" mean?

Answer (score 1):

Mountain Lion may not support this feature, but MDM providers like AirWatch have token/PIN based enrollment for just this purpose. Users are not requirement to input user information (although you can configure it that way if you like) and they are sent their token via email or SMS.

Answer (score 0):

Full *biometric authentication* is too advanced for the profile manager on Mountain Lion with Server installed. Furthermore, iOS doesn't log in using a pin or pass phrase except for the lock screen.

So, you could use profile manager to lock the devices remotely once they were enrolled, so there's nothing stopping you from remotely choosing a PIN for each device and mailing that to the account of a person assigned to that device.